# How to have clojure support related values in binding?

Tags: clojure

I am using binding as a means to make it easier to pass around state within a call.  I currently have something like the following

```
(binding [*private-key-path*  "/Users/dcapwell/.ssh/id_dsa"]
  (binding [*session* (session "localhost")]
   ...
```

The reason that I need to do this is that the session function requires *private-key-path* to be defined. Since binding doesn't allow related values, is there any simpler way to do the above without the needed nesting?

EDIT:

Currently prototyping using clj-ssh.ssh. The plan is to make most of my current usage of binding to be a static config (most are static values already, so read once on boot). Was using binding as a way to make prototyping easier so I didn't have to keep passing things around while seeing how the API worked.

I was just curios how I can get the bindings to be dependent on each other. When I use let, the second binding has access to the first one, but it seems that when I do this that the second binding doesn't have access to the first. I would assume there would be another function that acts like binding but would allow the second binding to have access to the first.  I can also see this not existing in the default since its more of state than anything else.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why don't you pass `*private-key-path*` to the session function as parameter. Anyway you might take a look at http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-redefs

Comment: Also, `binding` - like `let` - allows for multiple bindings to be given, e.g. `(binding [*out* some-stream, *err* some-stream] ...)`.

Comment: like James Sharp said, private-key-path should be parameter to session function. using binded globals for every configurable setting doesn't feel right at all.

Comment: Agree, I plan to rewrite this so this configs from a config. Mostly just wondering how I could have dependent if needed.

Comment: @JamesSharp I tried with-redefs and it seems that the behavior is the same in this case. The binding wont happen before the call to session.

Comment: I encourage you to use this pattern to manage state in your solution rather than messing up with bindings  https://github.com/stuartsierra/component

Answer (score 0):

Edited: some experiment in the REPL

```
(def ^:dynamic *a* "a not bound")
(def ^:dynamic *b* "b not bound")
(defn show-a! []
  *a*)
(binding [*a* 1 *b* (show-a!)] *b*) ;; => "a not bound"

(binding [*a* 1]
  (binding [*b* (show-a!)]
    *b*)) ;; => 1
```

I was surprised to know the given code is NOT the same as:

```
(binding [*private-key-path* "/Users/dcapwell/.ssh/id_dsa"
          *session*          (session "localhost")]
  ...)
```

so Clojure tends to have less parentheses than other Lisps in `let` forms cases but not `binding`.

Please think about your overall code (and/or API design?) again and again. Dynamic bindings are bad. You will suffer soon. Tip: make more and more code unit-testable.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, so I recommend this:

A feature called "Graph" for structural computation. Never worry about dependencies between functions again!

https://github.com/Prismatic/plumbing

Comment: The issue here is that *private-key-path* doesn't get bound before the call to session. So when session gets called, the value is nil (what its set to in the def)

Comment: agree that binding is prob a bad idea. currently using it just to prototype with the ssh lib so I can see how to break it.  I was just curious why private-key-path isn't bound by the time session was called.

Comment: You're right, `binding`'s nested binding forms are parallel, unlike those of `let`